# How to set static public ip for ambassador service in aks?

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, ambassador

Got following problem:
 - My setup is aks in azure. Inside got few services and [ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/) working in front of them.
 - I know how to setup public static ip for "regular" load balancer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip)
 - When im trying to do the same in my ambassador yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
(..)
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: XX.XXX.XX.XXX // <= line from microsoft documentation
  ports:
  - name: ambassador
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: ambassador-secure
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    service: my-selector
```

the static ip ive passed seems to be ignored and each time new one is being created.
Any ideas what im doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which resource group do you create the public IP address in? Can you also show the deployment YAML file?

Comment: are you passing resource group in the anotation of the service? (as per microsoft documentation example )
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource group location seems to be the root cause here.  If you have not put your public IP in the `MC_xxxx` resource group that AKS creates, the Kubernetes’ controller-manager won’t be able to find it since it is the default resource group that it looks under. Unless one is specified in your service manifest using the right service annotation.

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: myResourceGroup
  name: azure-load-balancer
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 40.121.183.52
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-load-balancer
```